# checking if one or more $_GET are set

Tags: php, mysql

ill try again :/

im setting up a blog page,

i want it to show posts via, poster or catagory or month or year, or a combination.
but only if the $_GET is in the url. if not and they just go to blogs.php i want it to just show the 12 most recent posts. no i have the catagory working on its own and poster working on its own.

here is my code so far, after editing it out a bit

```
                    <?php 


$category = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['Category']);
$Poster = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Poster']);
$Month = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Month']);
$Year = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Year']);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM blog, blog_poster, blog_category WHERE blog.category = '$category' 
AND  blog_poster.pid = blog.posterid 
AND blog_category.ID = blog.category 

OR posterid = '$Poster' 
AND  blog_poster.pid = blog.posterid 
AND blog_category.ID = blog.category  
ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 5";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or print ("Can't select entries from table.<br />" . $sql . "<br />" . mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $date = date("D M d Y", $row['timestamp']);

$title = stripslashes($row['title']);
$entry = stripslashes($row['entry']);
$id = $row['id'];
$entry =substr($entry, 0, 250);


?>

            <div class="ribbon">
                    <div class="wrapAround"></div>
                    <div class="tab">
                        <span class="blogDate"><?php echo $date; ?></span>
                        <span class="blogPostInfo">Posted by <a href="#"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></a> <!--|  <a href="#">0 Comments</a --></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="blogPostSummary">
                    <h1><span><b><?php echo $title; ?></b></span></h1>
                    <div class="blogPostImage">
                        <a href='cs_blog/content.php?id=<?=$id?>'class="img">
                        <img src="../images/content/blogs/cs_blog/date/headers/blog-post-01.JPG" width="556" height="133" alt="blog post image" /></a>
                  </div>
                    <p>
                        <?php echo $entry."..&nbsp;<br><a href='content.php?id=$id'>Read more...</a>"; ?>
                    </p>
                    <p></p>
                </div>



                <!-- End of Content -->
                <?php }; ?>
```

ben

Comment: what is the problem with `isset` ?

Comment: isset seems like it would be the correct way here

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve.  What have you tried so far? Show us your code - we may be able to point out the errors.

Comment: `function get_post( $key, $default){if( isset( $_POST[$key]){return $_POST[$key];} return $default;} $category = mysql_real_escape_string( get_post( 'Category', 'default category));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$conditions = array();
if( isset($_GET['Category']) ) $conditions[] = "category='". mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['Category']) . "'";
if( isset($_GET['Poster']) )   $conditions[] = "poster='". mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['Poster']) . "'";

if(!empty($conditions))
    $conditions = 'where ' . implode(' AND ', $conditions);
echo 'select * from table ' . $conditions;
```

Comment: worked thanks mate, just had to an { on the if(!empty and an else on the end thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$category='DefaultCategory';
$poster='DefaultPoster';
$month='defaultMonth';
$month='defaultYear';

if(isset($_GET['Category']))
{
   $category = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['Category']);
}
if(isset($_GET['Poster']))
{
   $Poster = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Poster']);
}
if(isset($_GET['Month']))
{
   $Month = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Month']);
}
if(isset($_GET['Year']))
{
   $Year = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Year']);
}

$query="insert into sampleTable(category,poster,month,year)
 values ($Category,$Poster,$Month,$Year)";
```

OR if you have set default values for all fields in table design
then you can insert only provided fields